# How do I replace this while loop which does nothing but creates a wait for a condition to be fulfilled?

Tags: objective-c, while-loop, segue

Here's my `while` loop in Objective C :

```
while(!aConditionIsSatisfied) 
{
    // Do Nothing
}

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:selfSequeIdentifier sender:self];
```

Is there a better way to do this?

To be more concrete, I am on a UITableView on which :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //check the Tow
    if(indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        //SHOW ALERT
    }

    if(ALERT IS DISMISSED)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:selfSequeIdentifier sender:self];
    }
}
```

However, I am having problems dismissing the alert. Hence, the segue either never happens or happens immediately. I am trying to mimic a completion block here.

Comment: Delegates, notifications, Key-Value Observing... There are many options. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: ANYTHING IS BETTER THAN THAT!!!  (At the very absolute minimum you must place a wait operation inside the loop -- wait for 100 ms or so.  Otherwise that loop can consume all the CPU and nothing else will get done -- your condition will never be satisfied.)

Comment: I know. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many better ways but they require a bit more code. What you've got there is called a "spin loop" or a "polling loop" (you're spinning in a loop doing nothing but checking/polling a variable).

A much better solution is an active one, where you use some syntonization variable such as a mutex that you use to block until the condition is met. This requires cooperation from whatever code is currently setting your `aConditionSatisfied` state though it would have release the mutex.

The basic order of things is:

1) Main code initializes a mutex to place it into a state indicating its resource is currently owned.

2) Main code enables the worker to do its thing.

3) Main code waits until the mutex can be received. (It currently cannot be received because of the initialization in step 1.

4) Worker starts and does whatever it needs to do.

5) Worker releases the mutex.

6) Main wakes up due to the mutex release and can continue on.

http://ekle.us/index.php/2007/01/mutexes_in_cocoa_1 has an example of setting up a mutex using `NSLock` in Cocoa.

---

**Update, since the question changed to have more relevant context:**

Since you're using an alert, just set yourself as the delegate and provide a method such as:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:selfSequeIdentifier sender:self];
}
```

If you want to know which button was used to dismiss the alert, use `buttonIndex`.

Related to the first (more generic) question and my answer, you could still use a mutex with this, but it's really not necessary.

Comment: I ended up doing 

[self.whateverView.view removeFromSuperView]
[self performSegueWithIdentifier....]

Thanks for your help.